# Yarn MapReduce stuck at state ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM

Tags: mapreduce, hadoop-yarn, hadoop2

Hi I am new to Hadoop and trying to run a mapreduce at pseudo cluster mode in my local machine. But everytime I submit a job, it gets stuck at

```
YarnApplicationState:   ACCEPTED: waiting for AM container to be allocated, launched and register with RM.
```

Here are my config files:

yarn-site.xml

```
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
    <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
    <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.maximum-am-resource-percent</name>
    <value>1.0</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.class</name>
 <value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.server.resourcemanager.scheduler.capacity.CapacityScheduler</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>3000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.scheduler.maximum-allocation-mb</name>
    <value>7000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.nodemanager.resource.memory-mb</name>
    <value>10000</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8032</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8030</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
    <value>127.0.0.1:8031</value>
</property>
```

maperd-site.xml

```
<property>
        <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
        <value>yarn</value>
</property>
<property>
  <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
  <value>localhost:54311</value>
 </property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.map.memory.mb</name>
    <value>2048</value>
</property>
<property>
    <name>mapreduce.reduce.memory.mb</name>
    <value>3072</value>
</property>
```

DFS replication is 1 in my config and trying to run only 1 job at a time, but that too stucks waiting for AM.
jps gives me all deamons running fine :

```
a45e60ebc96f:hadoop-2.7.3 z002ksm$ jps
27345 NodeManager
27907 Jps
27141 SecondaryNameNode
4485 
27258 ResourceManager
26958 NameNode
13615 GradleDaemon
27039 DataNode
```

Here are screenshots of cluster UI:[Hadoop UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mcdI6.png) and [Hadoop UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUkRZ.png)